# How to return html markup from custom block Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have created new block like a plugin in a custom module. This block must render Login/Register links. Here is the function build() code:

```
public function build() {
        // Init metadata.
        $cacheableMetadata = new CacheableMetadata();

    $build = [
      '#cache' => [
        'contexts' => [ 
          'user', 
        ],
      ], 
    ];

    if ($this->currentUser->isAnonymous()) {
      $build['links']['login'] = [
        '#title' => $this->t('Login'),
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#url' => Url::fromRoute('user.login')
      ];

      $build['links']['register'] = [
        '#title' => $this->t('Register'),
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#url' => Url::fromRoute('user.register')
      ];
    } else {
      $build['links']['cabinet'] = [
        '#title' => $this->t('My cabinet'),
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#url' => Url::fromRoute('user.page')
      ];

      $build['links']['logout'] = [
        '#title' => $this->t('Logout'),
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#url' => Url::fromRoute('user.logout')
      ];
    }

    // Apply metadata.
    $cacheableMetadata->applyTo($build);

    return $build;
  }
```

How can I wrap every link with `<li class="header__top__li">`

And also wrap all these li with
`<ul class="header__top__ul">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added needed attributes to the links:

```
public function build() {
    // Init metadata.
    $cacheableMetadata = new CacheableMetadata();

    $build = [
      '#cache' => [
        'contexts' => [ 
          'user', 
        ],
      ], 
    ];

    if ($this->currentUser->isAnonymous()) {
      $build['links']['login'] = [
        '#title' => $this->t('Login'),
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#url' => Url::fromRoute('user.login'),
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => [
            'header__top__a'
          ]
        ]
      ];

      $build['links']['register'] = [
        '#title' => $this->t('Register'),
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#url' => Url::fromRoute('user.register'),
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => [
            'header__top__a'
          ]
        ]
      ];
    } else {
      $build['links']['cabinet'] = [
        '#title' => $this->t('My cabinet'),
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#url' => Url::fromRoute('user.page'),
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => [
            'header__top__a'
          ]
        ]
      ];

      $build['links']['logout'] = [
        '#title' => $this->t('Logout'),
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#url' => Url::fromRoute('user.logout'),
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => [
            'header__top__a'
          ]
        ]
      ];
    }

    // Apply metadata.
    $cacheableMetadata->applyTo($build);

    return $build;
  }
```

And created an html structure in block.twig.file:

```
<div class="header__top__right">
    <ul class="header__top__ul">
        {% for link in content.links %}
            {{ link }}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use hook_theme for that

```
function hook_theme() {
  return array(
   'block_name' => array(
            'variables' => array(),
            'template' => 'block_name',
        ),
  );
}
```

And in block_name.twig file you can get like this

```
<ul class="header__top__ul">
<li class="header__top__li"><a href="{{ links.login.url}}">{{ links.login.title }}</a></li>
<li class="header__top__li"><a href="{{ links.register.url}}">{{ links.register.title }}</a></li></li>
</ul>
```

Hope! it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I chose another, I think the easiest way, I just added needed attributes to the links and styled block in twig